# Include() not working with Take() when performing a split query

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have collection of Images in my Product class:

```
public ICollection<Image> Images { get; set; } = null!;
```

I ran into problem where Images are not being included when I try to take only 4 first products.
This code includes images

```
var products = await _context.Products
            .Include(x => x.Images)
            .AsSplitQuery()
            .ToListAsync();
```

But this does not include them

```
var products = await _context.Products
            .Take(4)
            .Include(x => x.Images)
            .AsSplitQuery()
            .ToListAsync();
```

[This is SQL generated with Take](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vs54g.png)

[This is without Take](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfphK.png)

Also when I am including other entities, Images are also being included.
For example, I have Brand field in Product class

```
public int BrandId { get; set; }
public Brand Brand { get; set; } = null!;
```

And this code includes both Brand and Images

```
var products = await _context.Products
            .Take(4)
            .Include(x => x.Images)
            .Include(x => x.Brand)
            .AsSplitQuery()
            .ToListAsync();
```

Why it does not include Images when I use Take method?
I can change to a single query or use Select() to specify what i need to get and it will work.
But I want to know what is the problem with split query.
I use PostgreSQL as my database.

Comment: You need to put the include right after the Products before the take: "var products = await _context.Products
            .Include(x => x.Images)
            .Take(4)
            .AsSplitQuery()
            .ToListAsync();" did you try this?

Comment: Yes, I tried this. It didn't work

Comment: @tapeex Is it necessary for you to use `AsSplitQuery`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `Take()` before `Include()`, EF Core generates a SQL query that includes a `LIMIT` clause to fetch only the specified number of products. However, when EF Core splits the query and executes separate queries for related entities, it doesn't include the `LIMIT` clause in those queries.

You can try removing `AsSplitQuery()` =>

```
var products = await _context.Products
    .Take(4)
    .Include(x => x.Images)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Or

Split the queries =>

```
var products = await _context.Products
    .Take(4)
    .ToListAsync();

foreach (var product in products)
{
    await _context.Entry(product)
        .Collection(x => x.Images)
        .LoadAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EF Core is generating a SQL query that includes a `LIMIT` clause to fetch only the specified number of products. However, when EF Core splits the query and executes separate queries for related entities, it doesn't include the `LIMIT` clause in those queries. This use can clearly see in the generated queries.

You could use the split query if this fulfils your requirement.

```
var products = await _context.Products
    .Take(4)
    .Include(x => x.Images)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Or you can run separate queries.

Comment: I get only 4 products, so it is okay. But if there were more of them, it would lead to cartesian explosion if I use single query, as far as I know. 
Anyway, I don't get the part about LIMIT. I see that the generated SQL code has LIMIT clause in both queries, when I use Take method. And when I include other entities, like Brand, Images are also being included. But SQL queries are alike, except for joining Brands part. Here is the [SQL code with joining Brand](https://imgur.com/a/VKiiiUt)